# Tablero de ajedrez

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que está función en JavaScript produzca un tablero de ajedrez de cualquier tamaño?

```js
let tamaño = 8;
let tablero = "";

for (let x = 0; x < tamaño; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < tamaño; y++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
      tablero += " ";
    } else {
      tablero += "#";
    }
  }
  tablero += "\n";
}
console.log(tamaño = tablero + tamaño());
```

Comment: Ajedrez? Dependería de cómo defina uno el cambio en la ubicación de las piezas, habría más peones? Si es para pintar sólo el tablero, pues usas la variable tamaño que tienes ahí y ya está, no?

Answer (score 0):

Si se cambia el valor de tamañó y en el console.log final solo se imprime tablero, eso debería ser sufuciente para que se dibuje el tablero de la cantidad establecida en tamaño.

**Quedaría así:**

```
let tamaño = 8;
let tablero = "";

for (let x = 0; x < tamaño; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < tamaño; y++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
      tablero += " ";
    } else {
      tablero += "#";
    }
  }
  tablero += "\n";
}
console.log(tablero);
```

---

Esta línea `console.log(tamaño = tablero + tamaño());` quizás podría sugerir que la idea es pasarle un valor quizás a una función y que en base a ese valor se cree solo el tablero con la cantidad correspondiente.

**En ese caso se podría crear la siguiente función:**

```js
function dibujarTablero(tamaño) {
  let tablero = "";

  for (let x = 0; x < tamaño; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < tamaño; y++) {
      if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
        tablero += " ";
      } else {
        tablero += "#";
      }
    }
    tablero += "\n";
  }
 return tablero;
}

// Y finalmente para ver el resultado
console.log(dibujarTablero(10))
// En lugar del 10 se puede poner el número deseado
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay poco más que aportar la respuesta de Luis, pero encontré que con caracteres unicode el tablero se ve genial.

```js
function dibujarTablero(tamaño) {
  let tablero = "";

  for (let x = 0; x < tamaño; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < tamaño; y++) {
      if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
        tablero += "⬜";
      } else {
        tablero += "⬛";
      }
    }
    tablero += "\n";
  }
 return tablero;
}

// Y finalmente para ver el resultado
console.log(dibujarTablero(8))
// En lugar del 10 se puede poner el número deseado
```

Comment: Si, se ve genial. Pero un cambio tan pequeño no justifica publicar una respuesta nueva. Podrías haberlo sugerido como un comentario o quizá en una edición.

Comment: Yussef, recordá explicar siempre _cómo funciona el código_... Puede que para vos sea claro, pero para otros lectores no. Tenés varias respuestas en donde escribiste frases similares a "esto tal vez pueda funcionarte" seguido de solo código.

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias por tu concejo lo guardaré en mi caja de tesoros